# create a web application using google analytics api and its client google-api-python-client?

Tags: python, google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-api-python-client

I was going through googles's api [python-client-library](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/apis/analytics/v3) and [google analytics api](https://developers.google.com/analytics/) . I was able to do all steps mentioned in official docs but then I got some doubts. Since I've never done this kind of thing before, so I need your valuable suggestions/tips.

**My Goal:** 
Want to design a web application in Python(using django/flask) and [google-api-python-client](https://github.com/google/google-api-python-client/). I have few matrices(coming from my web ecommerce product that is using GA.) and I'm not sure if google analytics dashboard by default support at that deep level. so I will use Google's analytic api to customize data according to my need and show in my analytic web app(which can be accessed by any one).

**Doubts/Queries:**

1) first of all which reporting api I would be needing for this [mentioned here](https://developers.google.com/analytics/). core api or metadata api?
2) while I was setting up the project and client key, I chose 2nd option(OAuth 2.0 client ID)
[image]

is that ok or should I chose service account? once I selected 2nd options there were couple of radio buttons(web, android, ios, other, etc.) I chose `other` or should I chose `web`?

3) once i chose `other` option from radio button list, I executed my script and it prompt a browser to ask for permission, I allowed. here my question is if I put my application on production would there not be any browser, what would happen in that case?

I would really appreciate if you can help me in these queries, sorry for long question, this is my first question.

PS: Bottom line is how one should structure and develop there analytic web application in general.

Answer (score 0):

The key thing to understand is that Google Analytics is an [authenticated API](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2). It is designed make it easy to allow the end user to access their own data. It is designed to be hard to allow the end user to access data they do not own.

If you are building a web application to allow your users to access their own private data It is recommended that you use a client side authentication method, such as in [this example](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/quickstart/web-js) or [this example](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/embed/v1/?hl=en).

If you are trying to build a web application that shares your private data with your users there are a few ways to go about it:

1. You could collect the data server side in python using a [service account](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/quickstart/service-py) (note you will have to add the service account the GA account you wish it to have access).
2. You can take a [hybrid approach](https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/embed-api/server-side-authorization/) and have a service account generate an access token and use the embed api to actually make the query.

In the end I would encourage you to spend some time to read [Using OAuth 2.0 to Access Google APIs](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2), and understand senarios descussed and ask yourself which of these senerios will work best for my application.

Comment: Whose data is being accessed? Does the data belong to the end user? or does it belong to you the developer?

Comment: That plugin will help you collect ecomerce data. The Analytics platform can be thought of as three types of interactions: Collection, Configuration, and Reporting. That plugin is a collection plugin which enriches the data which GA collects wrt ECommerce.

But to answer your earlier question. You are trying to create a dashboard to share your private data with other individuals, who do not necessarily have access to your GA account.  If that is the case I would use a service account. Collect the data server side and display it however you want. in what ever dash boarding system you want.